# Label foreground in toolbar

Tags: wpf, toolbar, foreground

I have a toolbar in my WPF window as shown in bellow, please help me change labels foreground color dynamically in code behind.
Thanks...

```
 <DockPanel Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ToolBar Name="MyToolBar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                     FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FFEEF5FD" Foreground="Black"              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
               
                <Button Name="BtnSubmit" Style="{DynamicResource TStyle}" Click="BtnSubmit_Click" Tag="New" Height="52" Width="60"
                        IsDefault="True" Margin="0,0,0,1">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0" Height="54"  
                        <Image Source="/Img/Save 04.png" Height="25" Margin="16,0"/>
                        <Label Content="Save" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                               
                <Button Name="BtnApply" Style="{DynamicResource TStyle}" Click="BtnApply_Click" Tag="New" Height="52"
                        IsDefault="True" Margin="0,1,0,2" Width="85">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0" Height="52" Width="82">
                        <Image Source="/Img/ApplyIcon.png" Height="25" Margin="29,0,26,0"/>
                        <Label Content="Edit" Margin="-15,0,-23,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"                                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
               
            </ToolBar>
        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Set the Foreground property of Label? You should really replace the Label with a TextBlock.

Comment: Thanx, I replaced the label with text block, It looks better know.

Comment: But how can I change its foreground color in code behind dynamically.

Comment: I use this code to change toolbar back ground color in code behind (MyToolBar.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#" + bgColor));)

Comment: But what about text block foreground color?

Comment: I like to change all of my text block foreground color in the toolbar by a foreach() loop, please can u help me

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change the `Foreground` of all `TextBlock` elements you must define a `Brush` resource and assign it to all relevant `TextBlock` elements using `{DynamicResource}`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonLabelForegroundBrush" Color="Black" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <DockPanel>
    <ToolBar>
      <Button>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource ButtonLabelForegroundBrush}" />
      </Button>
    </ToolBar>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void ChangeTextBlockForeground()
{
  var brush = FindResource("ButtonLabelForegroundBrush") as SolidColorBrush;
  brush.Color = Colors.Red;
}
```

Comment: Thankx, dear friend. That is absolutely what I want